# Как организовать быстрое развертывание ОС на virtualbox (коробки)?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, виртуализация

Хочу иметь возможность без заморочек, быстро разворачивать линукс на виртуальной машине. Как это организовать?

Сейчас мне приходится каждый раз устанавливать ОС. Для удобства я установил линукс, настроил его, завершил работу и копировал виртуальный диск. Теперь когда мне нужна чистая система - я просто копирую тот файл виртуального диска, создаю машину и указываю ей диск с свежей системой и запускаю.

Это лучше чем каждый раз ставить систему снова, но всё равно это довольно топорно и медленно. А образ диска занимает около 50гб.

---

Я уверен в том, что есть более простой способ разворачивания системы готовой к работе, но я в этом юниор, поэтому решил спросить у вас.

Слышал что-то о каких-то коробках, может быть мне нужно это?

И ещё один вопрос, docker ведь это не то что мне нужно? Я хочу создать несколько коробок, например линукс минт для одних задач и дебиан для других и иметь возможность из одного файла поднять рабочую ОС.

Comment: virtual box позволяет делать экспорт машин. А его можно импортировать нужное кол-во раз. Он должен быть меньше по размеру.

Comment: в коробке есть клонирование вирт. машин, причём как полное, так и связное. В купе с механизмом снепшотов, думаю последнее тебя вполне устроит. Если пользуешься гуйнёй, то ищи кнопку с овечкой, если консолью, то внимание на `VBoxManage clonevm`.

Comment: Эммм... `vagrant`?

Answer (score 1):

Для конфигурации системы с нуля существует отдельный класс ПО - configuration manager, к нему относятся chef, saltstack, ansible, puppet и другие. Моим непосредственным фаворитом является chef (мне очень сложно вообще работать со всем остальным из-за того, что называется opinionated approach); его область применения можно грубо описать как "поставить MySQL, создать такие-то конфигурационные файлы, перезагрузить сервис", описание подобных вещей, конечно, весит какие-то смешные килобайты. Судя по вашему описанию - это то, что вам нужно; Chef может быть немного сложен для управления одним десктопным хостом, поэтому имеет смысл посмотреть, как работают все вышеописанные инструменты.

> Слышал что-то о каких-то коробках, может быть мне нужно это?

Скорее всего вы слышали про Vagrant, который является системой автоматизированного создания и менеджмента виртуальных машин. Он позволяет задать исходный образ для виртуальной машины, способ, которым она будет конфигурироваться (одно из вышеперечисленных решений или простой набор shell-команд), и сохранить это в виде простой конфигурации. Скорее всего это ровно то, что вы ищете, но без дополнительного контекста сказать сложно (но совершенно точно вы сможете описать виртуальную машину одним конфигурационным файлом и воссоздавать ее везде, где есть Vagrant и Virtualbox).

> И ещё один вопрос, docker ведь это не то что мне нужно?

Докер в глобальном смысле - это просто еще одно средство виртуализации (хоть и не полноценной), поэтому в этом контексте это что-то вроде замены Virtualbox. Несмотря на то, что у него есть некоторые преимущества, я бы не рекомендовал его использовать для этих целей, просто потому что его основное использование лежит довольно далеко от вышеописанного, и в результате доступный инструментарий и ресурсы по настройке могут несколько страдать (хотя, безусловно, функционально в докере вы можете сделать практически все то же самое, что и в виртуалбоксе).

Comment: Vagrant это удобно, судя по описанию. Ставлю сейчас "[коробку от laravel](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/homestead)", посмотрю как это выглядит. У меня возник небольшой вопрос, возможно ли сконфигурировать "коробку" так, что бы не пришлось скачивать образ системы каждый раз при поднятии? Как-то указать на локальный файл или типо того. А то сейчас образ качается уже около часа и скачалось только 11%, в то время как образ debian с оф сайта, мой браузер качает за минуту

Comment: К сожалению, базовый образ так или иначе понадобится, но, судя по всему, его можно добавлять из файловой системы через `vagrant box add <path>`

Comment: а если я захочу создать ещё одну машину из этой же коробки, образ снова будет скачиваться или скачанный образ где-то сохранится и всё будет быстрее? (спрашиваю потому, что у меня всё ещё 15% и при всем желании я не могу самостоятельно выяснить это сейчас)

Comment: @TryCatch они сохраняются в $HOME/.vagrant.d/boxes, поэтому исходный образ второй раз скачиваться не будет.